# Elementor and WordPress - php special characters must be escaped

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, elementor

I am trying to insert this code to > Elementor > Custom Code to change the Sale Badge Text in WooCommerce

add_filter(‘woocommerce_sale_flash’, ‘edit_sale_badge’); function edit_sale_badge() { return ‘TEXT-GOES-HERE’; }

From this page: https://pluginsforwp.com/blog/change-sale-badge-woocommerce/ – But I dont know how to make it work, can anyone help me? Can PHP be added to Elementor custom code? Thanks!

wrap the code with th PHP but getting the error: php special characters must be escaped

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You cant insert php in Elementor Custom Code area.. You must add this via functions.php in your child theme. Or you can add this via other plugins (2).

Look also here: https://elementor.com/help/custom-code-pro/

(2): https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/insert-php-code-snippet/

Comment: Meaning isn’t possible to add the PHP code directly into the custom code area and I will need to add it to my child theme or use a plugin, correct?

Comment: Yeah correct. Idk why some guy downvote my answer. You can only add JS,HTML and CSS to custom code area from elementor.

Answer (score 2):

Did you wrap your code with

```
<?php and ?>
```

So that it looks like the following:

```
<?php
add_filter('woocommerce_sale_flash', 'edit_sale_badge');
function edit_sale_badge() {
    return 'TEXT-GOES-HERE';
}
?>
```

In your Link, they add it to the Themes Functions:
functions.php
Why not do it also there?

Note: there is a difference between the following symbols `, ´ and '. You want to use the last one.

Comment: Thank you! When I try to wrap the code with "<?php and ?>," I receive an error from Elementor that states " special characters must be escaped: [<]." I don’t want to place any code on the child theme. I would like to place all code on Elementor custom code area. Maybe Elementor doesn’t allow PHP?

Comment: Correct the symbols ` and ´ to this one '.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what symbol you are talking about. Can you update the code you provided, thank you so much!

Comment: See this screenshot: https://paste.pics/LO2C7

Comment: Your screenshot is different than what you posted here.
Here you are using ` and ´. On your screenshot, you are using the correct symbol ' and '.

Comment: Right! I updated it. Unfortunately, the code doesn’t work. It is not the code itself, but the PHP-wrapped code, As far as I know. Aty this point looks like PHP can’t be added to elementor.

Comment: Did you try with deleting the < and >.

Comment: https://paste.pics/LO2MA

Comment: Yes, but it didn’t work...

Comment: So now you only have this: https://paste.pics/LO34T ? What is the error now?

Comment: The error is on <?php -   https://paste.pics/LO2C7 After removing "<", there are no errors, but the code still doesn’t work. You can see when the code is working by its color,  as you can see, all the code is grey, when working it should be like the one you pasted above.

Comment: This was still the old screenshot. Make a new without the < / >. Not sure if elementor makes colors. The problem may be somewhere else. Have you tried, just as a test, to add the theme? That would help to pinpoint the error, so as if it works there or not.

Comment: I have confirmed with elementor. PHP is not possible to add. Thanks for your help!