Elementor Custom code | InputField query selector
I am using elementor custom code and elementor form. I would like to have an auto selector for airports using the API. My code is currently as follows and I am getting a special character error for < & >. Any help would be much appreciated.
const accessKey = 'xxxx';
const    url=`https://app.goflightlabs.com/retrieveAirportaccess_key=${accessKey}&query=${encodeURIComponent(query)}`;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const inputField = document.querySelector('#departure');
    const suggestionBox = document.createElement('div');
    suggestionBox.classList.add('suggestion-box');
    inputField.parentNode.appendChild(suggestionBox);

inputField.addEventListener('input', async function() {
    const query = inputField.value;
    return;  // Start suggesting after 2 characters

    try {
        const response = await fetch(`[url]?query=${query}`);
        const suggestions = await response.json();

        suggestionBox.innerHTML = '';  // Clear previous suggestions

        suggestions.forEach(suggestion  {
            const suggestionItem = document.createElement('div');
            suggestionItem.classList.add('suggestion-item');
            suggestionItem.innerText = suggestion;
            suggestionItem.addEventListener('click', function() {
                inputField.value = suggestion;
                suggestionBox.innerHTML = '';
            });
        suggestionBox.appendChild(suggestionItem);
        });
        } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching suggestions:', error);
        }
        });

        document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
            if (!suggestionBox.contains(event.target) && event.target !== inputField) {
            suggestionBox.innerHTML = '';
        }
    });

});
I am hoping for airport suggestions to be retrieve from the api and used in a selector function of the form.

What does the error message specifically say and what line is throwing it? Does your fetch work and does the error come after the response is sent? If so, it would be helpful to mock up the response, since we can't actually call it.

My apologies, the above code has the parts with the error removed.
"if (query.length < 2) return;" &
"suggestions.forEach(suggestion => 2  {"
Were the 2 lines showing the error, 'Special Characters must be escaped :[ < ].'
The code doesn't run, i am not sure if elementor custom code is the correct place to implement it.

Please [edit] your question to include the "parts with the error", so we know specifically where that part goes. Did you attempt to escape the special characters?

The code doesn't run and i am not sure of how to escape the characters.

Doesn't run at all? Because of that particular err or other errors? What have you tried to use to escape the characters? What variable(s) contains the special characters?

It's specifically the '<' and'>' characters. I am currently adding the code in elementor custom code, so running it is isn't an option and VS code won't work because of the need to use fields from my websites form.

Your code here doesn't show any angle brackets. You should post the code that actually contains the error. Maybe this would help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75463764/elementor-and-wordpress-php-special-characters-must-be-escaped

Maybe I'm mistaken (havn't used elementor custom code) but the URL you give to fetch seems wrong. Shouldn't it be ${url}?query=${query} instead of [url]?query=${query}?
